# How can I directly run a file in IE (11) using javascript in Test Complete

Tags: javascript, testcomplete

I am using IE 11 and I want to automatically download and run a file using javascript in Testcomplete. The problem is that the Run or Save buttons are inaccessible. I can get the download window (as shown in the attached screenshot) but unable to click the Run button.

I tried recording a script but that uses coordinates to reach the button.

Here's the code with the mix and match of recording and scripting-

```
 if (Aliases.browser.BrowserWindow.FrameNotificationBar.DirectUIHWND.Visible == true)
  {
  Log.Message("IE download prompt");

  Aliases.browser.BrowserWindow.FrameNotificationBar.DirectUIHWND.Click(758, 63);

  }
```

How can I get the particular run object?[image: download prompt/window IE]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the **DirectUIHWND** window name to the **UIAutomation** list of accepted windows. To do this, open the **Tools | Current Project Properties** dialog and add the window name to the list in the **Open Applications | UI Automation** group.

[image]